# How to set search box in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I'm using this search form, is there any plugin to perform search in WordPress ? 
I use link as button here.

```
<div class="search_area">
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">

<div class="search_txt">Search</div>                                    

<?php $search_text = __(" " ); ?>           

<div class="search_field"> <input type="text" class="field"  value="<?php echo $search_text; ?>" onblur="if (this.value == '')  
{this.value = '<?php echo $search_text; ?>';}"  onfocus="if (this.value == '<?php echo $search_text; ?>')  {this.value = '';}" />  
</div>

<div class="search_icon">

<a name="sub" href="#" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image28','','<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/search_icon-hover.jpg',1)"> 
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/search_icon-normal.jpg" name="Image28" width="28" height="24" border="0" id="Image28" /></a>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

WordPress default Search form is really powerful and can customize.

```
<div class="only-search with-image">
<?php get_search_form(); ?>
</div>
```

Just paste the above code and it will display search box with a search image inside the box. [Function Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_search_form)

If you wants to create your own search page then [**refer this**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page).

Also there is a plugin to increases WordPress' default search functionality. - [**Search Everything**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-everything/)

Check it. Cheers !!!